# VSCode Code Runner not activating virtual environment at the first run, but works for subsquent runs in the same terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\Python_Workspace\Password Manager GUI> python -u "d:\Python_Workspace\Password Manager GUI\main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python_Workspace\Password Manager GUI\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
PS D:\Python_Workspace\Password Manager GUI> & "d:/Python_Workspace/Password Manager GUI/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1"
(.venv) PS D:\Python_Workspace\Password Manager GUI>
```

As you can see it runs activate.ps1 after the first run, I don't have this problem with python terminal in VS Code, but due to my reliance on Code Runner, its exhausting me. I tried executor map fix in settings.json, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be supported by the `Code Runner`, but the developer of `Code Runner` has not fixed this problem.

Some people have submitted this feature request in 2019 but without any response. refer to [here](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/434)

It seems like you need to bear on this inconvenience for now.